# Undefined reference when calling an external function of the same module

Tags: module, fortran

I have a number of functions in a module, and I need one function to use other of the same module as the input of of a third function.

```
FUNCTION FUN2(W)
    use gabqs, only: GABQ2
    IMPLICIT REAL*8 (A-H,O-Z)
!   REAL*8 W
    EXTERNAL FUN3
    R1 = 1.e-5
    R2 = 10.e0
    TOL = 1.E-2
    CALL GABQ2(FUN3,R1,R2,SUM2,TOL,IER)
    Fun2=sum2*W
    RETURN
    END

FUNCTION FUN3(R)
    use dielectricFun, only: elflev
    IMPLICIT REAL*8 (A-H,O-Z)
    REAL*8 K,W
    PI=3.1415926536

    CALL elflev(w,k,r,ximelf)
    fun3=ximelf*4.d0*pi*(r**2.d0)
    RETURN
    END
```

I can compile the module but when I compile the main program i get an error in the module where the two functions are:

```
 .\integralfun.o:integralFun.F90:(.text+0x16c): undefined reference to `fun3_'
```

I have all the use statement in the main program.

Comment: Are `FUN2, FUN3` in the same module? If so then you dont need the `EXTERNAL FUN3` line.

Comment: By the way, it is best practice to use `implicit none`.

Comment: Yes FUN2 and FUN3 are in the same module. I have been using Fortran for short, and as I understand, as I'm using FUN3 as an input for other function it has to be external, is this wrong?

Comment: @fcr It is wring, only in the other function, that receives a function, must declare the argument. External is the worst way how to do it, it is much better to use an interface block. We have many questions about this.

Comment: Please also take the welcome [tour].